# dpkg and equivs

Tags: dpkg, packaging, metapackages, equivs

i am trying to make a metapackage with equivs, creating the package is working perfect, but installing it is giving me an error:

```
Selecting previously deselected package testdeb.
(Reading database ... 219619 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking testdeb (from testdeb_1.0_all.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of testdeb:
testdeb depends on apache2; however:
Package apache2 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing testdeb (--install):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
testdeb
```

to fix that i have to run: apt-get install -f

is there a way around this ?

Comment: Are you installing with `dpkg -i`? AFAIK `dpkg` doesnot resolve dependencies `apt` does. `dpkg` just refers to missing dependencies if any.

Comment: yes i tried that for testing on my local machine, installing via apt is working, thanks !

Comment: @sagarchalise can you post that as an answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

Posting comment as the answer:

Are you installing with dpkg -i? AFAIK dpkg doesnot resolve dependencies apt does. dpkg just refers to missing dependencies if any. – sagarchalise Dec 1 '11 at 2:19